# Will these command sufficiently to connect 2 raspberry pi together?

Tags: raspbian

I do not own raspberry pi so tested these commands in virtual machine. I clone 2 raspberry pi and and using the command sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.1 for Pi1 and sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.2 for Pi2 but it not able to connect to each other by using ssh -X pi@192.168.1.1 on Pi2 but i wonder if tested on these steps on actual raspberry pi, will it work or i still need to configure some steps in between?

Comment: How did you connect the two together?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> i wonder if tested on these steps on actual raspberry pi, will it work or i still need to configure some steps in between?

If you use the default [Raspberry Pi OS](https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/operating-systems/) on both RasPis and connect them wired to a working network with a DHCP-server both will work out of the box. You don't need any configuration.

With WiFi you can use a simple setup file with your WiFi Network name and connection password as shown at [Wireless connectivity](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/README.md).

Comment: The OP doesn't have any Pi

Comment: @Milliways I know, I only answered his question. That's the reason why I quoted it.